# JBoss pool has negative value for IdleCount

Tags: jdbc, jboss, wildfly

Sometimes, when checking my JBoss 7.1 connection pool status (JDBC), I see a negative value for *IdleCount*, like in the following example where ***"IdleCount" => -7***.

Can someone explain me the meaning of this negative value?

```
"pool" => {
"ActiveCount" => 13,
"AvailableCount" => 230,
"AverageBlockingTime" => 1L,
"AverageCreationTime" => 76L,
"AverageGetTime" => 2L,
"AveragePoolTime" => 306L,
"AverageUsageTime" => 241L,
"BlockingFailureCount" => 0,
"CreatedCount" => 13,
"DestroyedCount" => 0,
"IdleCount" => -7,
"InUseCount" => 20,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdleCount is calculated using ActiveCout - InUseCount.

e.g. IdleCount = ActiveCount - InUseCount => 13-20 = -7

That is why it is showing -7 in the pool stats.

refer to the [code base](https://github.com/ironjacamar/ironjacamar/blob/c97d3ae1c0d76b302d4de67daa2ee85dceadfaa2/core/src/main/java/org/jboss/jca/core/connectionmanager/pool/PoolStatisticsImpl.java#L820)